# RODBC insertion performance(very slow) in R into ORACLE Database using sqlQuery

Tags: r, database, oracle, performance, rodbc

We are trying into insert a dataframe into Oracle database using RODBC connection and with sqlQuery function. We are also using `mclapply` function to achieve parallelism. The insertion performance is very slow as it is taking 6 hours to insert 3.6 million records. There are no logs created in the database side.

Please let us know how to improve insertion performance in R and let us know if any more information is required.

```
Target1Conn<-odbcConnect('TARGET_DATABASE','USERNAME','PASSWORD')
if(nrow(InputData)>0)
{
     sqls<-sprintf(paste0('insert into ', 
         outputTableName,'(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15) 
         values(%s)'), 
         apply(InputData, 1, function(i) paste(i, collapse=",")))
 }
 mclapply(sqls, function(s) {
     sqlQuery(Target1Conn, s)
 },mc.cores=4)
```

Comment: Did you try `sqlSave` instead of looping through rows: `sqlSave(Target1Conn, InputData, outputTableName, fast=TRUE, append=TRUE, rownames=FALSE)`?

Comment: Hi Parfait, we have tried sqlSave but it is creating table default datatypes and not with specified data types. More over it is taking same time to load data.

Comment: Can you try the `odbc` package which follows R's DBI standard (that includes RJDBC, ROracle, RMySQL, RSQLite) and use `dbWriteTable`?

Comment: we are facing some issues with odbc package and trying to resolve it. Once the issue is resolved, we will try to implement it with odbc and test the performance.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, appending millions of records with `INSERT...VALUES` is suboptimal compared to a single insert select as well-known blogs stress:

[dba-oracle.com](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_data_load.htm):

> **Don't use standard SQL inserts** - They are far slower than other approaches.

[asktom.oracle.com](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1415454871121):

> The fastest would be to disable the indexes (mark them unusable) and do this in a SINGLE insert

[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18414578/1422451) @Lokesh:

> A select insert is the fastest approach as everything stays in RAM.

---

Therefore, consider building a staging, temp table with RODBC's [sqlSave](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RODBC/versions/1.3-16/topics/sqlSave) or DBI's [dbWriteTable](https://rdrr.io/cran/DBI/man/dbWriteTable.html). And to help align variable types. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39242242/1422451) by @Linda.

```
RODBC::sqlSave(Target1Conn, InputData, "myTempTable", fast=TRUE, append=FALSE, rownames=FALSE)

DBI::dbWriteTable(Target1Conn, InputData, "myTempTable", append=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Then, run a ***single*** insert select (and try with Oracle's [APPEND](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/append-hint) hint as shown below):

```
sql <- "INSERT /*+ append */ INTO myFinalTable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,
                                  col6, col7, col8, col9, col10,
                                  col11, col12, col13, col14, col15)
        SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,
               col6, col7, col8, col9, col10,
               col11, col12, col13, col14, col15
        FROM myTempTable"


RODBC::sqlQuery(Target1Conn, sql)

DBI::dbExecute(Target1Conn, sql)
```

---

Further optimization techniques. Be sure to discuss with your DBA before proceeding.

- Used `BULK COLLECT` (if available) inside a stored procedure still using above temp table.

  Oracle *(run only once)*

  ```sql
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE load_data
  IS
  TYPE TObjectTable IS TABLE OF ALL_OBJECTS%ROWTYPE;
  ObjectTable$ TObjectTable;

  BEGIN
    SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO ObjectTable$
      FROM myTempTable;

    FORALL x in ObjectTable$.First..ObjectTable$.Last
     INSERT INTO myFinalTable VALUES ObjectTable$(x) ;
  END;
  ```

  R

  ```r
  RODBC::sqlQuery(Target1Conn, "EXEC load_data")
  DBI::dbExecute(Target1Conn, "EXEC load_data")
  ```
- Have R export a csv or other delimited text file

  ```
  utils::write.csv(InputData, "/output/path/inputdata.csv")
  # data.table::fwrite(InputData, "/output/path/inputdata.csv")  # ALTERNATIVE
  ```

  Then use Oracle's [`SQL*Loader`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/part_ldr.htm) which is great and designed for bulk inserts and as advised by [@Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24758415/1422451).

  1. Save below as `.ctl` text file such as *myload.ctl*

     ```
     OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
     LOAD DATA 
       INFILE "/output/path/inputdata.csv"
       INTO TABLE "myschema"."myFinalTable"
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
       (col1 INTEGER, 
        col2 DATE 'YYYY-MM-DDD', 
        col3 VARCHAR(50),
        col4 NUMBER(10,2),
        col5 CHAR(255),
        ...)
     ```
  2. Run `sqlldr` command line *(outputs errors and issues in same directory)*

     ```
     sqlldr CONTROL=myload.ctl, LOG=myload.log, BAD=myload.bad USERID=user/pwd
     ```

  Of course, R can automatically create the above `.ctl` with `writeLines()` and call `sqlldr` at command line with `system()`.
- Temporarily disable indexes, load new data using above temp table, and then re-enable indexes. See [procedure here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3526027/1422451). This might be necessary also for `SQL*LOADER`.